# Ruby while and if loop issue

Tags: ruby

```
x = 16
while x != 1 do
  if x % 2 == 0
    x = x / 2
    print "#{x} "
  end
  break if x < 0
end
```

Hi, the result I get from above is 8 4 2 1 . Is there any way to remove the space at the end?

Comment: Don't print the values into the loop. Put them into a list (array) then, after the loop, join the array items using space as glue.

Comment: @axiac: A good idea but the extra storage required for this always needs to be considered, however small.

Comment: By running the script I have the `8 4 2 1 ` result

Comment: @Bathsheba, storage is _not_ an issue you should consider in Ruby at this level. Ruby is made for beautiful code, it is not the main objective to win at performance

Comment: Therefore there is enough material here for an alternative answer. SO works best with multiple answers that are put through the peer review process.

Comment: Bathsheba has a point here (even if the effect on this question is insignificant).  We, the developers, should always struggle to make the code run fast and consume less resources. Working with nowadays computers that have plenty of resources (compared to 20-30 years ago) we too often forget about performance of our code.

Comment: @TheCha͢mp: You should at least *consider* it, which is what I was trying to say. An immediate rejection of the consideration is permissible.

Comment: @roppo aside from the white space annoyance, are you aware that this code enters an infinite loop if `x` is not a power of `2`?

Answer (score 5):

One of Rubys main features is its beauty - you can shorten that loop to a nice one liner when using an array:

```
x = 16
arr = []

arr.push(x /= 2) while x.even?
puts arr.join(' ')
# => "8 4 2 1"
```

---

<sup>* As sagarpandya82 suggested `x.even?` is the same as using `x % 2 == 0`, leading to even more readable code</sup>

Comment: Honestly, it looks like PHP. In Ruby the upfront declaration of the local variable is considered to be code smell, as well as `while` loop.

Comment: @mudasobwa on a second thought, you are right. I am curious how a pure Ruby solution, unaffected by PHP thinking, looks like :-)

Comment: @mudasobwa, I assume the code is part of a study exercise. It's readable and Rubyish enough for that context. Of course you would add a method when actually doing something with the code....

Comment: I think this is the most elegant solution. In a similar vein you could also use `until x.odd?`.

Answer (score 4):

Don't print the values into the loop. Put them into a list ([array](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Array.html)) then, after the loop, [join](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Array.html#method-i-join) the array items using space as glue.

```
x = 16
a = []
while x != 1 do
  if x % 2 == 0
    x = x / 2
    a << x
  end
  break if x < 0
end
puts '<' + a.join(' ') + '>'
```

The output is:

```
<8 4 2 1>
```

As @Bathsheba notes in a comment, this solution uses extra memory (the array) to store the values and also the call to `Array#join` generates a string that doubles the memory requirements. This is not an issue for small lists as the one in the question but needs to be considered the list becomes very large.

Comment: I think the break line is superfluous here:)

Comment: @sagarpandya82 it was in the original code. I only changed the part that handles the output, didn't even try to make it look good.

Answer (score 3):

```
loop.reduce([[], 16]) do |(acc, val), _|
  break acc if val <= 1

  acc << val / 2 if val.even?
  [acc, val / 2]
end.join ' '
```

Comment: Suggestion to use `even?` here instead of `val % 2 == 0`.  +1 for using loop which I believe is more idiomatic.

Comment: No offense, but this version reminds me of Lisp & Prolog ;-) +1

Answer (score 0):

```
if x != 0
    print " "
end
```

is one way, having dropped the suffixed space from the other `print`. I/O will always be the performance bottleneck; an extra `if` will have a negligible effect on performance, and the extra `print` will merely contribute to the output stream which is normally *buffered*.